# Фоновое изображение в CSS

Tags: css, кодировка, background

Задал фоновое изображение через CSS. Как сделать, чтобы оно прикрепилось и никак не реагировало на другие элементы и элементы на него? А то я пытаюсь сделать margin параграфу, так изображение с ним двигается. Подскажите пожалуйста.
[image: Результат]

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
  src: url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: normal;
 width: 100%;
}
     /* Header*/
header {
 width: 1350px;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 0px auto;
}
header li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 20px;

}
header a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.header__feedback {
 float: right;
 width: 200px;
 height: 80px;
 font-size: 21px;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
.header__logo {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
.header__menu_list {
 display: inline-block;
}
.header__feedback_icon img {
 width: 20px;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 9px;
 margin-left: 4px;
}
.header__feedback_items {
 font-size: 14px;
 width: 156px;
 height: 38px;
 border: 1px solid #2f1059;
 border-radius: 5px;
 line-height: 38px;
 margin-top: 8px;
 margin-left: 25px;
}
.header__feedback_button a {
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.header__feedback_number {
 color: #2f1059;
}
.header__menu_list_item1 {
 margin-left: 50px;
}
.header__menu_list_item2,
.header__menu_list_item3,
.header__menu_list_item4,
.header__menu_list_item5 {
 margin-left: 20px;
}
     /* Header END*/
     /* Section1*/
section {
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.section1 {
 background: url('../img/background.jpg') no-repeat center top;
 width: 1962px;
 height: 655px;
}
.section1__heading_paragraph_up {
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 175px;
} 
.section1__heading h1 {
 font-size: 43px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Тренировка</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <nav>
   <div class="header__logo">
    <img src="img/logo2.png" alt="Logo">
   </div>
   <div class="header__menu_list">
    <ul>
     <li class="header__menu_list_item1"><a href="#">Инфраструктура</a></li>
     <li class="header__menu_list_item2"><a href="#">Планировки и цены</a></li>
     <li class="header__menu_list_item3"><a href="#">Материалы и отделка</a></li>
     <li class="header__menu_list_item4"><a href="#">Документы</a></li>
     <li class="header__menu_list_item5"><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="header__feedback">
    <div class="header__feedback_number">
     + 7 (495) 544-23-12
    </div>
    <div class="header__feedback_items">
      <div class="header__feedback_icon">
        <img src="img/icon_phone.png" alt="icon">
      </div>
      <div class="header__feedback_button"> 
        <a href="#">Заказать звонок</a>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </header>
 <section class="section1">
  <div class="section1__heading">
   <p class="section1__heading_paragraph_up">
   Дом готов идет внутренняя отделка. Срок сдачи: Февраль 2016
   </p>
   <h1>Ваша квартира в новостройке ждет вас</h1>
   <p class="section1__heading_paragraph_down">Уютные квартиры в центре города и в 5 минутых от р. Волга</p>
  </div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Изучите https://webref.ru/css/background-origin https://webref.ru/css/background-position  https://webref.ru/css/background-size

Comment: Дописал center и top. Все равно оно позиционируется так же, как и параграф. Вместе с ним двигается..

Comment: добавьте ```.section1__heading:before,
.section1__heading:after {
 display: table;
 content: "";
 clear: both;
}```

Answer (score 0):

```
.section1 {


    width: 1962px;
    height: 655px;
    background: url('../img/background.jpg') no-repeat center top;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```